# Sublime Text indentation

Tags: sublimetext3

How to force ST3 to use spaces for indentation, after a comment? For ex., now it's like that:

```
(tab)/**
(tab) * some text (tab)another text
(tab) */
```

but it should be

```
(tab)/**
(tab) * some text (space,space,space,space)another text
(tab) */
```

Sorry if this question is not really about "programming" itself, but it's very annoying and I googled about an hour, and couldn't find anything.

EDIT: I use tab indentation for default and want keep it that way. All I want to change, is the indentation AFTER a line has started.

Comment: You have in the bottom right corner "spaces: x". Click on that and the menu will open. The first option is "Indent using spaces". Check that.

Comment: In the bottom corner of what? And won't that change the whole indentation to spaces??

Comment: Of sublime ( at least for ST2). You can switch it back to _tab_ after your done.

Comment: and i'll have to do this every time i want to indent some text in the midline????

Comment: Yes. This is one way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and add the following:

```json
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "    "}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "comment" }
    ]
}
```

If this file doesn't contain any content yet, make sure to enclose everything in square brackets `[]`:

```json
[
    { "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "    "}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "comment" }
        ]
    }
]
```

This will insert 4 spaces whenever <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed inside a comment, otherwise it retains its normal behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is it! Is there also a way to force similar behavior always, when there's already some text at the beginning of this line? So before you got any text on the line, you'll get tabs, and as soon as you type even a single letter, you'll get spaces from there on.

Comment: I noticed that even thou it adds the spaces, the completely break the alignment.. You always get 4 spaces, doesn't matter where the next tabstop is.

Comment: That's correct - it does exactly what you indicated you wanted in your question. If you want to align with tabstops, why not use tabs?

Comment: in regards to your first comment, yes, it's probably possible, but you may need to write a plugin to analyze the current line and see if there are any characters other than tabs and newlines in it. I guess the larger question is, why do you need this behavior?

Comment: Because it's the way to do this. Tabs for indentation, spaces for alignment within the line! Imagine you use tabs to align your variable values (after the "=") and the someone else opens it, with another tab setting - it will completely break the alignment. All major IDE's do it this way, that's why I don't understand why sublime does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your settings file:

```
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

**EDIT**

I did not see your edit at first. I do not think there's a way to configure sublime so that you have `tabs` at the beginning of the line and then `spaces`, I'm sorry but I think you'll have to do that manually, or write your own plugin.

Alternatively you could use the setting mentioned, then disable it and use the multiline-select and manually remove the spaces in the beginning of the lines and then add the tabs.

For multiline use:

```
ctr+alt+<arrow up/down>
```

Comment: That is not quite suitable.. Doing that on every comment.. But thank you for your input!

Comment: Well whenever something isn't quite suitable, it's a golden opportunity for writing a plugin.